# prevent empty strings from being part of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I make my function such that it only sends data when I have something filled out in the input fields? I have a standard of 4 input fields, whenever I insert data in 2 input fields it will send 2 words into my array (that works), but it also sends 2 empty strings. I however want the array to only exist with values and not empty strings. a quick example: You as a user decide to fill out 2 of the 4 input fields (because they are optional). I now want to prevent the 2 other input fields to send an empty string to my JSON aswell. So only what the user has filled out should be part of the array.

This is how my function looks in order to create the input fields for my array:

```
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue) {
  console.log(cValue);
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var div = $('<div/>');
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
      'class': 'form-group form-control syllable syl ' + TT ++,
      'type': 'text',
      'value': (cValue[i] !== undefined) ? cValue[i] : '',
      'placeholder': 'Syllables',
      'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ i +']'
    });
    div.append(wpInput);
  }
  return div;
}
```

This is the AJAX call:

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
  console.log(setMainObjectArray());

  $.ajax({
    url: 'saveJson.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id: getUrlParameter('id'),
      getExerciseTitle: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
      language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
      application: 'lettergrepen',
      'main_object': {
        title: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
        language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
        exercises: setMainObjectArray()
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(errorThrown);
    console.log(textStatus);
  });
}
```

How setMainObjectArray() looks like:

I am talking about the array `syllables`.

```
 function setMainObjectArray() {
var exercises = [];
var eBlocks = $('.eBlock');

eBlocks.each(function(i, eBlock) {
    var exObject = {
      word: $(eBlock).find('input.ExerciseGetWordInput').val(),
      syllables: []
    };
    $(eBlock).find('input.syllable').each(function(j, syll) {

      exObject.syllables.push($(syll).val());            
    });

    exercises.push(exObject);
  });

return exercises;
}
```

Comment: How is the first block of code related to the second? You don't appear to be using the values from the inputs in the AJAX request. That said, all you need to do is check the value of the inputs before sending the request and then add them if a value is provided.

Comment: The first block (I think you are refering to the function) is how the input field is created/what I have done. I thought that would be usefull info. I editted my post a bit to clarify what I mean with empty strings.

Comment: May be add 'required'  attribute to all input fields.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but that is not what I am looking for. it's optional whether you fill out all the 4 input fields or not. however the problem: Let's say you only fill out 2 and leave the other 2 empty, it will show in my array 2 words and 2 empty strings.

Comment: What array? You mean in `setMainObjectArray()`? Need to know what this function does then.

Comment: i added the function of setmain, please note the "syllables" array

Comment: Side note: you do `var eBlocks = $('.eBlock');` and after that you do `$(eBlock).find()`. You already wrapped `eBlock` in jQuery so you can just use `eBlock.find()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to avoid the syllables being filled with empty values.

```
if($(syll).val() !== "") {
    exObject.syllables.push($(syll).val());
}
```

Comment: And this will prevent empty strings from being send to my JSON? (I mean, will it ONLY send input fields with a value to my JSON) and empty strings won't be a part of the array: Example: 4 input fields, I fill out 2 of them and let the other 2 empty (because it's optional). will the array only contain 2 words?

Comment: You add the `exObject` to the `exercises` which is the return value of your function. This return value is used in the JSON data for your ajax request. So yes should be.

Comment: Thank. You. Very. Much. I have been struggling with this problem for about 3 weeks now. @Mark Baijens

Answer (score 0):

You can put IF condition and SKIP if value is empty

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {

  // This code will skip AJAX call if value is empty
  if($('#getExerciseTitle').val() == '') {
     return false;
  }

  console.log(setMainObjectArray());

  $.ajax({
    url: 'saveJson.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id: getUrlParameter('id'),
      getExerciseTitle: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
      language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
      application: 'lettergrepen',
      'main_object': {
        title: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
        language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
        exercises: setMainObjectArray()
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(errorThrown);
    console.log(textStatus);
  });
}
```